# MATLAB parfor loop & random simulations

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am running multiple simulations using the `parfor` loop of MATLAB. The simulations run in a time-slotted fashion.

In these simulations, flows arrive at a server, finish there session and leave the server, of course, the arrival process is random (i.e: the departure process is also random). For each simulation, there are 100 arrivals, which means that for 2 simulations, under the `parfor` loop, the 100 arrivals are less likely to occur at the same slot in the 2 simulations (in other words: it is less likely that 2 simulations are perfectly identical).

I am calculating some metrics at the end of each simulation. After running 20 simulations I observe that for some simulations the values of the metrics are identical, see lines: 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 15, 17 and 20:

```
1  12.1380000000000 8.67000000000000e-07    2126951.79378669
2  38.3040000000000 2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
3   7.95200000000000    5.68000000000000e-07    2724654.56890640
4   38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
5   21.0080000000000    1.50057142857143e-06    1653785.58341616
6   38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
7   21.0080000000000    1.50057142857143e-06    1653785.58341616
8   38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
9   11.9820000000000    8.55857142857143e-07    1827114.39301842
10  7.63000000000000    5.45000000000000e-07    2662037.48091595
11  8.28400000000000    5.91714285714286e-07    2584669.40096182
12  38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
13  16.7040000000000    1.19314285714286e-06    1745020.01488049
14  20.6480000000000    1.47485714285714e-06    1131378.20827498
15  38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
16  9.45400000000000    6.75285714285714e-07    2330783.95992713
17  38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
18  20.5960000000000    1.47114285714286e-06    1349336.77768965
19  9.54400000000000    6.81714285714286e-07    2344366.38257795
20  38.3040000000000    2.73600000000000e-06    964079.569727887
```

Getting results that are very identical makes me think that the simulations were perfectly identical also, which means that the arrival/departure to/from the server occurs at the same slots in different simulations.

Why I am getting perfectly similar results when the simulations are random?

If simulations are perfectly identical they will not be useful for me since I want to use results to determine confidence intervals...

I tried my best to make the question clear unfortunately I can not put code here (1xxx line of code in the main function)

**EDIT**

I tried to simulate the arrival process only:

**The script to launch simulations in parallel:**

```
    numSim = 20;
    numSlotPerSec = 10;
    arrivalRatesVec = [0.2 0.3];
    
   parfor i = 1:numSim
        [arrivals] = simulationFunction(numSlotPerSec, i,arrivalRatesVec);
   end
```

**The function that runs the simulations:**

```
function [arrivals] = simulationFunction(numSlotPerSec, numSim, arrivalRatesVec)

arrivals = [];
numSlots = 1;
nextArrival = 1 + round(numSlotPerSec*exprnd(1/sum(arrivalRatesVec)));
arrivals = [arrivals nextArrival];
output_file = ['ResTest_' num2str(numSim)];

while numSlots < 10000
        numSlots = numSlots + 1;
        nextArrival = nextArrival + max(1, round(numSlotPerSec*exprnd(1/sum(arrivalRatesVec))));
        arrivals = [arrivals nextArrival];
        eval(['arrivals_' num2str(numSim) '= arrivals']);
        save(output_file,['arrivals_', num2str(numSim)]);
end
end
```

I noticed that arrivals occur in different slots but I still don't understand why my metrics are perfectly identical.

The function `eval` can cause problems when it is called in a `parfor` loop? I saw on MATLAB that it might not access the correct workspace.

**EDIT 2**

I launched 20 simulations again in parallel just to see if the arrival of events happens at the same slots

Figures below (corresponding to simulation 2 and 13) that users arrive at the server at the same slots (see columns "entry" for arrivals and "exit" for departures)

[image]

[image]

Which means that these simulations are identical.

Also, I tried to check if `eval` causes the problem, so I saved one of my metrics without using `eval` and turns out that there are duplicated values.

Comment: See [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/control-random-number-streams-on-workers.html). Does "the values of the metrics are identical" necessarily mean that the random numbers were identical too? If so, you can make the random numbers repeatable, despite `parfor`, and then explore the issue as explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/repeat-random-numbers-in-parfor-loops.html). Remember you can always reduce your problem and reproduce a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post here on SO.

Comment: You don’t need `eval` there, you should remove it. Simply save `arrivals` to your file. When loading the file, you can use the functional form of `load` to combine the loaded data into an array.

Comment: @Cris Luengo in my code (the complete version) I use eval to generate variables and files names that correspond to the simulation arrival rates I am using.

Comment: Is there any method otger than eval to generate variables and files names?

Comment: You don't need eval to generate file names (you're doing this right in your example code here), and you should **never** generate variable names dynamically. It makes  your code slower, harder to read, harder to debug, and more likely to break in the future. It is never necessary to dynamically generate variable names. Search for "dynamic variable name matlab" on Stack Overflow and you'll find many posts explaining why this is bad, and what to use instead.

Comment: Actually generating names dynamically makes processing data easy: plots, computing metrics... Any other solution than eval?